# How to delete the outside of a shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i wanna delete the red outside of my black circle. in photoshop you just use magic wand and select it and delete that half of the shape boom done but in illustrator no.... magic wand doesnt seem to work as it would in photoshop and i cant find a way of deleting the red outside the black circle anyone able to point me in the correct direction?

i was thinking this would take me 5 min to make mysself a vector for my website but no.... iv been trying to do this for the past hour and a half now. please help.

using pathfinder doesnt seem to work cos it deletes everything but the outside of the black circle.

most methods iv found seem to delete the inside now whats on the outside of a shape...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's circle, you can make a copy of it without any holes. Arrange it on the top and place to exactly the same place as your current black circle is. Use the Alignment panel or move with smart quides on. Disable other snaps.

Select your pink shape and the new circle on top. Open the Pathfinder Panel (Window > Pathfinder) and click Intersect. The extras vanish.

Another way is to use the new circle as clipping mask. That has an advantage: It's possible to release the mask and do edits. There's also a disadvantage: The hided part shows its existence just under the surface  every time you hover with the mouse over it. The hided parts also take their full size space if you copy to Photoshop.